# MS Word repeating Content Control Field not working - if from Template

Tags: templates, ms-word

I am creating a Word Template, on which there is to be a **repeating Content Control**.
i.e. the User enters a field, which is repeated on each page. *

The template appears to work fine, but when you create a NEW doc. based on it - the repeated field does NOT get filled as it is linked to the **template** original, not to **itself**.

Can this be overcome?

- *We are doing this using Developer>>DesignMode and Copying the field, then pasting it with PasteSpecial>>PasteAsLink.*

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: FWIW, there seems to be some confusion about "repeating content controls", and "content controls whose content is automatically replicated at various points in the document". I think you are talking about the latter. To make *that* work, what you do is insert content controls that are "mapped" to the same property. "Linking", e.g. via Copy->Paste Link is a legacy technology that does not do the same thing and is highly likely to cause more trouble than it's worth. Without VBA or similar, you can only map to a small number of built-in or "recognised" properties, such as Author andTitle.

Comment: Again, this is off-topic. However, if @jonsson is correct in the interpretation of your question, take a look at my page on repurposing built-in mapped controls https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart and Greg Maxey's page on custom mapped controls: http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html. If you want help with these, ask in the appropriate place.